# How to structure databse of API usage history

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

I have a database of users for a web API, but I also want to store usage history for each user, i.e: page request count, data volumes, etc. What is the best way to implement this, in terms of database structure? My initial thought was to retain the main table, but then create a history table for each user. This seems horribly impractical, however. My gut feeling is that I probably need one separate table for usage history, but I am unclear as to how to structure it.

I am using SQLite.

Comment: Do you want details of each activity, or just statistical aggregates?  i.e. do you want to know that UserX made a specific request at 5 pm today, or do you just want a running total count of UserX requests?  That will greatly influence how to structure your schema.

Comment: @Jim The former - I want to keep track of requests and data volumes at particular points over time. An idea which has occurred to me since posting is to maintain a separate table with columns for request time, data volume, and a foreign key 'user_id' which references an entry for a specific user in the main table. This is also suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295388/database-design-for-user-entries-using-mysql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an event logging model (which is what you want), I can recommend two options

1. One table, lets call it `activity_log`.

   ```
    `activity_log`{
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     user_id MEDIUM INT NOT NULL,
     event_type VARCHAR(10),
     event_time TIMESTAMP 
            }
   ```

   For each event in your system affecting a user, you insert a record into this role (i believe the column names are self-explanatory). I believe SQLite doesn't provide native `TIMESTAMP` type so you'll have to handle the storage in your application code. What this design will leave you with a table that has the potential to grow very large, but it will give you fine grained statistics. SQLite doesn't support clustered indexes but there are some options [here](http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=PerformanceTuningWindows) that will help you out with performance tuning.
2. The same table as above, only instead of inserting a new row for every event, you're going to perform a conditional insert i.e. update existing rows for users already in and update for new users. This option will keep your table several times smaller than what you have above, but you'll only have access to the most recent use of your api.

If you can afford it, I'd say go with number 1.

Comment: Thanks. As it happens I can afford it, so I think I'll go with something similar to number 1.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my programs, I maintain a table of module usage per user. The structure of the table is

```
table id
user id
prog id
date/time
history flag (0=current, 1=history)
runs (number of time user has run program on date)
```

About once a week, I aggregate the data in the table: if user 1 has run program 1 twice on a given date, then initially there will be two entries in the table:

```
1;1;1;04/10/12 08:56;0;1
2;1;1;04/10/12 09:33;0;1
```

After aggregation, the table becomes

```
3;1;1;04/10/12 00:00;1;2
```

Whilst the aggregation loses the time part, no other data is lost and queries against the table will be quicker.